# Oracle MAF application hang on startup screen in iPhone 6 plus.

Tags: oracle-maf

Oracle MAF application hang on splash screen in iPhone 6 plus but working fine in iPhone 5.
Both device have same os: iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

Before 26th jan iphone 6 and 6+ was not supported in MAF.
check https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/announcing_oracle_mobile_application_framework

in new version of MAF 2.1 it is supporting xcode 6 that means it will support iphone 6 and 6+ both.